# How can i render super class view after subclass view render?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js, backbone-views

i cant call super class's render

```
Super = Backbone.View.extend({

     render : function(){
          //super class code here   (unable to call)
          return this;
     }

}); 

Sub = Super.extend({

     render : function(){
          //sub class code here    (called)
          return this;
     }

});

var view = new Sub();
view.render();
```

i want to call sub class render first and then super class render.
in some case, super class render first and then sub class render.

so, is it possible to code subclass render which 
call super class render before or after as per user requirement, **without changing Super class** 
and **without changing name of function**.

So, what am i missing?

thanks, in advance.

Comment: here, you override super class 's render in sub class . that's why super class render not called.

Comment: .extend is basically copying the properties/methods in your sub object with that of the super object. Which is why you cannot reference render in super because you've overridden it with render in sub. extend isn't creating a super class as you would think of it in other languages.

Comment: but as per my requirement, i must call super class render after  sub class render called.

Comment: Posted an answer with a different approach to achieve the same end result.

Comment: Updated my answer with your new requirements.

Comment: My updated answer meets both of these requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but you can call the render method on the prototype of Super in your `Sub.render` function :

```
Super = Backbone.View.extend({
     render : function(){
          console.log('super render');
          return this;
     } 
});

Sub = Super.extend({
     render : function(){
          console.log('sub render');
          Super.prototype.render.call(this);
          return this;
     } 
});

var view = new Sub();
view.render();
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WATqe/

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
Super = Backbone.View.extend({

     render : function(){
          //super class code here   (unable to call)
          if (typeof this.postRender === "function") {
            this.postRender();
          }
          return this;
     }

}); 

Sub = Super.extend({

     postRender : function(){
          //sub class code here    (called)
          return this;
     }

});

var view = new Sub();
view.render();
```

view.render() would call render on the super, which would then call postRender if it exists regardless of where postRender is defined (super, sub, subsub, etc).

**UPDATE: If you can't modify super then you could try:**

```
Sub = Super.extend({
    initialize : function () {
       if (this.render) {
           var render = this.render;
           this.render = function () {
               render.call(this);
               // sub class render code goes here
           };
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: i cant change function name render; i also use for initialize not only for render.. http://backbonejs.org/#View

Comment: in this approach this reference changed for sub class.

Comment: this still references the view.

Comment: Nice.. but then, how can i use it for initialize function too?

Comment: hmm. this approach cant use for initialize its works only for render.

Comment: You could always reference a method on the Super using the prototype chain. Super.prototype.initialize or Super.prototype.render

Answer (score 0):

You can construct life cycle as needed

e.g.,

in super

```
...
preRender_: function () {
    // maybe empty, for override
    ...
},
render_: function () {
    // do real render here
    ...
},
postRender_: function () {
    // maybe empty, for override
    ...
},
render: function () {
    preRender_();
    render_();
    postRender_();
}
```

in sub

```
// override preRender_, render_ or postRender_ as needed
```